# Как сделасть что бы когда кликал на кнопку,она не меняля цвет?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

У меня возникла проблема,когда я кликаю на кнопку,она почему то меняет цвет на синий.Мне нужно что бы цвет оставался белым.[image: Вот что я имею ввиду]

Пишу с помощью фреймворка Bootstrap.
Мой код:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 head_list "   >
                <li class="nav-item ">
                  <a class="nav-link active  " aria-current="page" href="#">Головна</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link  " href="#">Доставка і оплата</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                  <a class="nav-link " href="#"> Гарантія і повернення </a>
                
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link  " href="#" >Контакти</a>
                </li>
             </ul>
```

Comment: ```.nav-link:visited { color: #fff; }``` не помогает?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло `.nav-link:visited { color: #fff; }`